# Application Insights Analytics - Query union of 2 or more tables

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

How can I union tables and then apply a where filter? basically i want to find all items with the `operation_Id == X`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by specifying the tables for a union.

```
union table1, table2 | where operation_Id == "X"
```